# How can I play audio and video streaming in Firefox?

Tags: linux, firefox, streaming

I've seen couple of sites that stream audio to my browser like SoundCloud and Grooveshark, but Firefox doesn't reproduce them in Linux. How can I reproduce these streams?

The console gets filled with messages like these:

```
[10:48:25.960] HTTP "Content-Type" of "audio/mpeg" is not supported. Load of media resource http://stream168a.grooveshark.com/stream.php?streamKey=874a8938966d8a9aa9bc33463bda8157749479a7_529df641_1a00e4e_2f578ed_fe2e2f8c_36_0 failed. @ http://html5.grooveshark.com/#!/now-playing
[10:48:25.961] "MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that Firefox doesn't include the MP3, MPEG, H.264, etc. codecs by default, hence it relies on the system's installed codecs, which in the case of [Linux is GStreamer](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=794282). Normally, Firefox is built with GStreamer support, but you should check the `about:buildconfig` page in case this is disabled.

To enable GStreamer you should visit the `about:config` page and look for the `media.gstreamer.enabled` key. Toggle it to enabled and restart Firefox. Congrats you have audio stream support.

#### Still doesn't play!

Now you should be getting:

```
[10:48:25.961] "MEDIA_ERR_DECODEC_NOT_SUPPORTED"
```

or

```
[10:48:25.961] "MEDIA_ERR_NONE_SUPPORTED"
```

This is because of two reasons:

1. The version of Firefox you are using still doesn't offer [support for GStreamer 1.0](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=806917), so that you are able to reproduce in others players that uses GStreamer mpeg doesn't mean that you should be able too. Install the gstreamer plugins for 0.10 base/good/bad/ugly. In debian based distros should be:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-base gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
   ```
2. You are lacking some plugins. Make sure that you have the correct/complete plugins.

Comment: I'm running the firefox package for Fedora 19. My `about:buildconfig` has `--disable-gstreamer` in its "Configure arguments" section. How do I change it? (Besides that, there is no `media.gstreamer.enabled` key).

Comment: @Braiam you provided him a link in the chat?? Come on man, paste it here, so that we call can use it. :-/

Comment: @beginer it was a link about how to rebuild Fedora packages with different options https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package#.25build_section